# find gene name from liste to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I actually have to know if I got some gene if my result, to do so I have one list with my genes' names and a dataframe with the same sames:

For exemple

```
liste["gene1","gene2","gene3","gene4","gene5"]
```

and a dataframe:

```
name1          name2
gene1_0035     gene1_0042
gene56_0042    gene56_0035
gene4_0042     gene4_0035
gene2_0035     gene2_0042
gene57_0042    gene57_0035
```

then I did:

```
df=pd.read_csv("dataframe_not_max.txt",sep='\t')
df=df.drop(columns=(['Unnamed: 0', 'Unnamed: 0.1']))
#print(df)
print(list(df.columns.values))
name1=df.ix[:,1]
name2=df.ix[:,2]


liste=[]
for record in SeqIO.parse(data, "fasta"):
    liste.append(record.id)

print(liste)
print(len(liste))

count=0
for a, b in zip(name1, name2):

    if a in liste:
        count+=1

    if b in liste: 
        count+=1
print(count)
```

And what I want is to know how many time I find the gene in ma dataframe from my list but they do not have exactly the same ID since in the list there is not the _number after the gene name, then the if i in liste does not reconize the ID.

Is it possible to say something like :

```
if a without_number in liste:
```

In the above exemple it would be :
count = 3 because only gene 1,2 and 4 are present in both the list and the datafra.

Here is a more complicated exemple to see if your script indeed works for my data:
Let's say I have a dataframe such:

```
  cluster_name  qseqid  sseqid  pident_x
15  cluster_016607  EOG090X00GO_0035_0035   EOG090X00GO_0042_0035
16  cluster_016607  EOG090X00GO_0035_0035   EOG090X00GO_0042_0042
18  cluster_016607  EOG090X00GO_0035_0042   EOG090X00GO_0042_0035
19  cluster_016607  EOG090X00GO_0035_0042   EOG090X00GO_0042_0042
29  cluster_015707  EOG090X00LI_0035_0035   EOG090X00LI_0042_0042
30  cluster_015707  EOG090X00LI_0035_0035   EOG090X00LI_0042_0035
34  cluster_015707  EOG090X00LI_0042_0035   g1726.t1_0035_0042
37  cluster_015707  EOG090X00LI_0042_0042   g1726.t1_0035_0042
```

and a list : `["EOG090X00LI_","EOG090X00GO_","EOG090X00BA_"]`

here I get 6 but I should get 2 because I have only 2 sequences in my data EOG090X00LI and EOG090X00GO

in fact, here I want to count when a sequence is present only when it appears once, even if it is for exemple: `EOG090X00LI vs  seq123454`

I do not know if it is clear?

I used for the exemple :

```
df=pd.read_csv("test_busco_augus.csv",sep=',')
#df=df.drop(columns=(['Unnamed: 0', 'Unnamed: 0.1']))
print(df)
print(list(df.columns.values))
name1=df.ix[:,3]
name2=df.ix[:,4]

liste=["EOG090X00LI_","EOG090X00GO_","EOG090X00BA_"]

print(liste)


#get boolean mask for each column    
m1 = name1.str.contains('|'.join(liste))
m2 = name2.str.contains('|'.join(liste))

#chain masks and count Trues

a = (m1 & m2).sum()
print (a)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could convert your dataframe to a series (combining all columns) using `stack()`, then search for your gene names in `liste` followed by an underscore `_` using `Series.str.match()`:

```
s = df.stack()

sum([s.str.match(i+'_').any() for i in liste])
```

Which returns `3`

**Details:**

`df.stack()` returns the following `Series`:

```
0  name1     gene1_0035
   name2     gene1_0042
1  name1    gene56_0042
   name2    gene56_0035
2  name1     gene4_0042
   name2     gene4_0035
3  name1     gene2_0035
   name2     gene2_0042
4  name1    gene57_0042
   name2    gene57_0035
```

Since all your genes are followed by an underscore in that series, you just need to see if `gene_name` followed by `_` is in that Series. `s.str.match(i+'_').any()` returns `True` if that is the case. Then, you get the sum of `True` values, and that is your count.

Comment: Hi, thanks, I updated my first comment because I forgot to tell that I just want to count when the sequence ID appears once.

Comment: @Benjamin, in your updated example I get your expected outcome (`2`), with my code (as long as your liste is at it was in your original example, *i.e.* without the `_`)

Answer (score 4):

I think need:

```
#add _ to end of values
liste =  [record.id + '_' for record in SeqIO.parse(data, "fasta")]
#liste = ["gene1_","gene2_","gene3_","gene4_","gene5_"]

#get boolean mask for each column    
m1 = df['name1'].str.contains('|'.join(liste))
m2 = df['name2'].str.contains('|'.join(liste))

#chain masks and count Trues
a = (m1 & m2).sum()
print (a)
3
```

EDIT:

```
liste=["EOG090X00LI","EOG090X00GO","EOG090X00BA"]

#extract each values before _, remove duplicates and compare by liste   
a = name1.str.split('_').str[0].drop_duplicates().isin(liste)
b = name2.str.split('_').str[0].drop_duplicates().isin(liste)

#compare a with a for equal and sum Trues
c = a.eq(b).sum()
print (c)
2
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, I updated my first comment because I forgot to tell that I just want to count when the sequence ID appears once.

Answer (score 4):

### Adjusted for updated OP

find where sum is equal to 1

```
df.stack().str.split('_').str[0].isin(liste).sum(level=0).eq(1).sum()

2
```

---

## Old Answer

### `stack` and `str` accessor

You can use `split` on `'_'` to scrape the first portion then use `isin` to determine membership.  I also use `stack` and `all` with the parameter `level=0` to see if membership is `True` for all columns

```
df.stack().str.split('_').str[0].isin(liste).all(level=0).sum()

3
```

---

### `applymap`

```
df.applymap(lambda x: x.split('_')[0] in liste).all(1).sum()

3
```

---

### `sum`/`all` with generators

```
sum(all(x.split('_')[0] in liste for x in r) for r in df.values)

3
```

---

### Two many `map`

```
sum(map(lambda r: all(map(lambda x: x.split('_')[0] in liste, r)), df.values))

3
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, I updated my first comment because I forgot to tell that I just want to count when the sequence ID appears once.

Answer (score 4):

Using `isin`

```
df.apply(lambda x : x.str.split('_').str[0],1).isin(l).sum(1).eq(2).sum()
Out[923]: 3
```

Adding `value_counts`

```
df.apply(lambda x : x.str.split('_').str[0],1).isin(l).sum(1).value_counts()
Out[925]: 
2    3
0    2
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, I updated my first comment because I forgot to tell that I just want to count when the sequence ID appears once.

Comment: Hi, I do not really understand the output, what is 3 for exemple?

Comment: @Benjamin both column show up in the list , there is 3 row , both columns not show up there is 2